# How to know if user authorized by request header

Tags: php, laravel

I have api which accept request from authorized and unauthorized users.

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
if(isset($headers['authorization'])) {
        $user = auth()->guard('api')->user();
        $user_id=$user->user_id;
}
else{
        $user_id=null;
}
```

Here I know if authorized user sending or guest . But problem is android send header authorization with lower letter but iphone sends like Authorization . so how can I accept both

Comment: Headers can be forged very easily. Such a variant therefore opens up a major security gap.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use or condition for both variable you can do like this way

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
if(isset($headers['authorization'] , $headers['Authorization'])) {
        $user = auth()->guard('api')->user();
        $user_id=$user->user_id;
}
else{
        $user_id=null;
}
```

may it helps  ...

Comment: In this example, both vars ( `'authorization'` **AND** `'Authorization'`) must exists and not NULL. Is this your intention?